# Unable to select elements using Coded UI Test Builder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

Following the steps outlined in [Testing Windows Store Applications with Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305948.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), I've built a Windows Store app project (built and run in Windows 8.1, VS2013 Ultimate Update 2), and have added a "Coded UI Test Project", selecting "Edit UI Map or add assertions". After clicking OK to this dialog, I am sent to the Windows Start screen and can open the app.

However, at this point I cannot select elements using the cross-hairs of the Test Builder -- the app minimizes whenever I click on the little Coded UI Test Builder window. If I use the Ctrl+Shift+I shortcut to attempt to map an element I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." popup.

It seems like the Test Builder and the app aren't aware of each other. Suggestions?